# Unable to Import ScalarsConverterFactory

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have added

`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'`  to gradle file.

But still I am not getting import option in my retrofit. ScalarsConverterFactory always shows error.

```java
Retrofit retrofit =new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://192.168.1.1:9000").
addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create());
```

I tried changing versions of ScalarsConverterFactory() but no success.

Comment: Probably it's a stupid question, but have you done _"sync project with gradle files"_?

Comment: Yes.  I synced the gradle file.